# paypal reccuring express checkout what is return url having order id and order key?

Tags: php, paypal, woocommerce, express-checkout

This is i am in using woo-commerce checkout option. After payment i want return url having order id and order key.
my problem is that it only return without order id and order key.
any solution for my problem??
currently i getting return url is => example.com/checkout/order-received/?token=4688991269822.
but i want it like that => example.com/checkout/order-received/orderid/?key=wc_order_593bc1dcb4324
because if i choose another payment gateway instead of my custom payment gateway. When i click on place order the order is became complete with this type of url=> http://example.com/checkout/order-received/7170/?key=wc_order_593bc1dc2343
in this url it automatically pass these order id value and order key.
So how i get this type of url in Return url valiable in expresscheckout.php.
please help Thanks in advance.

This is expresscheckout.php

```
 require_once ("paypalfunction.php");

// ==================================
// PayPal Express Checkout Module
// ==================================

//'------------------------------------
//' The paymentAmount is the total value of 
//' the shopping cart, that was set 
//' earlier in a session variable 
//' by the shopping cart page
//'------------------------------------

//$paymentAmount = $_POST["Payment_Amount"];
//$paymentAmount = $_SESSION["Payment_Amount"];
$_SESSION["Payment_Amount"] = 0;

//'------------------------------------
//' The currencyCodeType and paymentType 
//' are set to the selections made on the Integration Assistant 
//'------------------------------------
$currencyCodeType = "USD";
$paymentType = "Sale";
#$paymentType = "Authorization";
#$paymentType = "Order";

//'------------------------------------
//' The returnURL is the location where buyers return to when a
//' payment has been succesfully authorized.
//'
//' This is set to the value entered on the Integration Assistant 
//'------------------------------------
$returnURL = site_url().'/checkout/order-received/';


//'------------------------------------
//' The cancelURL is the location buyers are sent to when they hit the
//' cancel button during authorization of payment during the PayPal flow
//'
//' This is set to the value entered on the Integration Assistant 
//'------------------------------------
$cancelURL = site_url().'/checkout/';

//'------------------------------------
//' Calls the SetExpressCheckout API call
//'
//' The CallShortcutExpressCheckout function is defined in the file PayPalFunctions.php,
//' it is included at the top of this file.
//'-------------------------------------------------
$resArray = CallShortcutExpressCheckout ($paymentAmount, $currencyCodeType, $paymentType, $returnURL, $cancelURL);

$ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
if($ack=="SUCCESS" || $ack=="SUCCESSWITHWARNING")
{
    RedirectToPayPal ( $resArray["TOKEN"] );
} 
else  
{
    //Display a user friendly Error on the page using any of the following error information returned by PayPal
    $ErrorCode = urldecode($resArray["L_ERRORCODE0"]);
    $ErrorShortMsg = urldecode($resArray["L_SHORTMESSAGE0"]);
    $ErrorLongMsg = urldecode($resArray["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]);
    $ErrorSeverityCode = urldecode($resArray["L_SEVERITYCODE0"]);

    echo "SetExpressCheckout API call failed. ";
    echo "Detailed Error Message: " . $ErrorLongMsg;
    echo "Short Error Message: " . $ErrorShortMsg;
    echo "Error Code: " . $ErrorCode;
    echo "Error Severity Code: " . $ErrorSeverityCode;
}
```

Comment: What for do you need the order ID and order key?

Comment: for completing the order process. because i want to create custom payment gateway via paypal reccurring method.
for example when we hit on place order button it complete the order process with url (example.com/checkout/order-received/7293/?key=wc_order_593bc1dcb4324) like this. in this url order id and order keyauto added in the url.